# How can I modify \@dottedtocline so it produces a continuous line instead of a dotted line for custom sectioning commands?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, tocloft

I need to represent deeply nested container structures in technical documents.
In my representation, each container needs to have its own section with sub-containers being included in sub-sections.
In order to achieve this, I have defined custom sectioning commands past subparagraph using titlesec's `\titleclass` command. My company's .sty file defines the leaders in the table of contents to be solid lines using:

```
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\rule{1pt}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0}
```

According to  the [tocloft package documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) this should result in `\@dottedtocline` producing solid lines instead of dotted ones.
While this works for the default sectioning commands, my custom commands still produce dotted lines in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% use solid lines instead of dotted lines for toc
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\rule{1pt}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0}

%% Indentation
\cftsetindents{section}{2em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2em}{4.0em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{2em}{5.0em}
\cftsetindents{paragraph}{2em}{6.0em}
\cftsetindents{subparagraph}{2em}{7.0em}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bf}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bf}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\bf}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}{\bf}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}

\newcommand{\levelOneSubsection}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
\newcommand{\levelTwoSubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{#1}}
\newcommand{\levelThreeSubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}}
\newcommand{\levelFourSubsection}[1]{\subparagraph{#1}}

% define \levelFiveSubsection
\titleclass{\levelFiveSubsection}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\newcounter{levelFiveSubsection}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand{\thelevelFiveSubsection}{\thesubparagraph.\arabic{levelFiveSubsection}}
\titleformat{\levelFiveSubsection}{\bf}{\thelevelFiveSubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\levelFiveSubsection}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@levelFiveSubsection{5}
  \def\l@levelFiveSubsection{\@dottedtocline{5}{2em}{8em}}
\makeatother

% define \levelSixSubsection
\titleclass{\levelSixSubsection}{straight}[\levelFiveSubsection]
\newcounter{levelSixSubsection}[levelFiveSubsection]
\renewcommand{\thelevelSixSubsection}{\thelevelFiveSubsection.\arabic{levelSixSubsection}}
\titleformat{\levelSixSubsection}{\bf}{\thelevelSixSubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\levelSixSubsection}{0pt}{21pt}{3pt}
\makeatletter
  \def\toclevel@levelSixSubsection{6}
  \def\l@levelSixSubsection{\@dottedtocline{6}{2em}{9em}}
\makeatother

%% Number down to levelSixSubsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{8}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

%% Indentation
\cftsetindents{section}{2em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2em}{4.0em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{2em}{5.0em}
\cftsetindents{paragraph}{2em}{6.0em}
\cftsetindents{subparagraph}{2em}{7.0em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\levelOneSubsection{levelOneSubsection}
  \levelTwoSubsection{levelTwoSubsection}
    \levelThreeSubsection{levelThreeSubsection}
      \levelFourSubsection{levelFourSubsection}
        \levelFiveSubsection{levelFiveSubsection}
          \levelSixSubsection{levelSixSubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: generated pdf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `\@dottedtocline` is as follows:

```
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\vskip \z@ \@plus .2\p@ 
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip 
\@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip \parindent #2\relax 
\@afterindenttrue \interlinepenalty \@M \leavevmode 
\@tempdima #3\relax 
\advance \leftskip \@tempdima \null \nobreak 
\hskip -\leftskip {#4}\nobreak
%%% dotfill here
\leaders \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
\hfill \nobreak 
\hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hfil \normalfont \normalcolor #5}\par }
\fi
```

The part responsible for the dotted line is `\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu`, so a small horizontal space (`\mkern`) of width `\@dotsep mu`, then a dot, then another small horizontal space. `\@dotsep` is defined as 4.5, a mu is a 'math unit' that is 1/18 em, an em is a unit that has the width of an M (in the active font size), so the distance in the dotfill is 1/4th of an M.

You can change this definition using the `etoolbox` package. This package provides the command `\patchcmd` with five arguments: the command to patch, the code in the command that you want to change, the replacement code, and code to be executed when the patch succeeds or fails, respectively (these last two arguments can be left empty).

Replacing the code above with `\rule{1pt}{0.4pt}` changes the dots of the custom sections into a line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% use solid lines instead of dotted lines for toc
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\rule{1pt}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu}%
{\rule{1pt}{0.4pt}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: to make the patched command a bit cleaner you can also replace the entire box with `\hrule`, as mentioned in the other answer:

```
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}}%
{\hrule}{}{}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The `tocloft` package isn't redefining `\@dottedtocline` to get its effects, but rather creates its own parameterized versions of the `\l@SECTION` commands for easy customization. You can dig into the later sections of the `tocloft` documentation  to see how this works.

Alternatively, you can use a bespoke macro like the following:

```
\def\@ruledtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hrule\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5%
                        \kern-\p@\kern\p@}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

which should be drop-in compatible with `\@dottedtocline` (note, I've not tested this so it might not work).